# Does TLS 1.3 encrypt alert messages?

Tags: encryption, tls, protocols

I'm working quite some time now with TLS 1.3 implementations (OpenSSL, WolfSSL), but I can't find anywhere in the TLS 1.3 drafts if alert messages should be encrypted or not. I personally thought only alerts send after the Client- and ServerHello will be encrypted, but I could not find any proof for this.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/180467/165253 might be helpful.

Comment: [Section 6 of TLS 1.3 draft 26](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-26#section-6) says *"Like other messages, alert messages are encrypted as specified by the current connection state."* -- And I'm not sure about this but at least in TLS 1.2 you would start out un-encrypted [internal state `TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-7.1) for each direction (client_write or server_write direction). So you'd *have* to send in the clear. Not sure. (And "TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL" is not mentioned in the TLS1.3 draft anymore.)

Answer (score 5):

The situation in TLS 1.3 regarding encryption of alerts is no different then with TLS 1.2. The [current draft 26](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-26#page-86) includes the same statement as you can find in the RFC of TLS 1.2:

> Like other messages, alert messages are encrypted **as
> specified by the current connection state**.

In [Appendix A](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-26#page-118) you also find the state diagrams which have additional information:

> ... clients may send
> alerts that derive from post-ServerHello messages in the clear or
> with the early data keys.  If clients need to send such alerts, they
> SHOULD first rekey to the handshake keys if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you have enough information to encrypt a record you should encrypt it and thus send ApplicationData holding the actual record as an encoded fragment.
If an error happens at the very beginning, then you send an unencrypted alert - that would be "handshake_failure" or "insufficient_security".

UPDATE:
If the first record e.g. ClientHello is invalid or something happens with parsing the first record, you should respond somehow to the other side. This is probably the only situation where such an unencrypted alert would be allowed (spec 6.2.). As far as I know, the spec never instructs that X should "terminate the connection" or "abort the handshake" by not specifying which alert to send before that.

Comment: Could you please add your reasoning for it?

Comment: If the first record e.g. ClientHello is invalid or something happens with parsing the first record, you should respond somehow to the other side. This is probably the only situation where such an unencrypted alert would be allowed (spec 6.2.). As far as I know the spec never instruct that X should "terminate the connection" or "abort the handshake" by not specifying which alert to send before that.

Comment: Would you kindly edit your answer instead?

Comment: I put my last comment into the answer.